# Image zoom is working once the page load, after changing the gallery, image zoom is not working

Tags: jquery, zooming, magnify

Once the page load, code is working fine, after trying to change the set of images through ajax within same div, without refreshing the page, then zoom is not working

I assigned a variable and set the zoom, then disable the zoom using destroy method, then again enabled the zoom..

```
    $(function(){
    var zoom;
     zoom = $(".rtwpvg-wrapper").find("img").magnify();
     $(".swatchinput").each(function(){
         $(this).click(function(){
            zoom.destroy();
            $(".rtwpvg-wrapper").find("img").magnify();
         });
     });
});
```

zoom Images should work even after replacing the images within same div

Comment: How is the HTML structured and which elements are replaced by JavaScript?

Comment: Hello, here I am sharing the demo link, please check this link, after selecting the size, imagezoom is not working https://www.mediajenie.com/demosites/tonirossi/product/maverick/

Comment: It might help to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.imageZoom.kill();
window.imageZoom = new ImageZoom(container,options);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.